# WSS 2.0 - Customizing document library toolbar

Tags: sharepoint, wss-2.0

I am using Windows Sharepoint Services 2.0 and was looking out for a way to add a new item to the Document Library toolbar along side 'New Document' menu item. I would like to add the menu item for the existing libraries as well as any new libraries created in future. Is this possible? I found that the toolbar items are defined in SCHEMA.xml file. But changing this would affect only the new libraries created right? Also editing this file seems complicated.

Appreciate any help.

Regards,
Jagannath

Comment: SORRY was clicking on the whole list of SPAM and went one too far!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WSS 2.0 reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa151976.aspx) : [Customizing the Toolbar for a List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms868603.aspx)T

Editing schema.xml with WSS 2.0 isn't easy. But it's the "better" way to update lists behavior.

When you udpate schema.xml for a list (custom or not, but you better create a custom one, [explanation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms868598.aspx)), some things a updated immediately, others after a iisreset, and some other only after creating a new list based on this schema file. Unfortunately, I don't remember all the cases.

Otherwise, you can try FrontPage 2003, but it depends on how many lists you have to update, and it breaks "[page ghosting](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/27673)".